# Are there any tools to visualize a RDF graph? (please include a screenshot)

Tags: rdf, semantics, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I'm looking for a tool that will render a RDF graph in a reasonably useful graphic format.  The primary purpose of the graphic format being inclusion into a PowerPoint slide or printing on a large plotter for management review.

I am currently using TopBraid Composer which does a reasonably well at visualizing a single entity but doesn't seem to have a clear way of visualizing the entire graph (as a whole).

Anyone know of any good solutions to this problem?

[image: TopBraid Composer Graph view screenshot]

Comment: List of lists of tools: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43605137/7879193

Answer (score 20):

Gephi was already mentioned, but I'll incode screenshots and a short description here.

[Gephi](https://gephi.org/) can not just visualize graphs but also supports analyzing, layouting and further importing and exporting. There is a Semantic Web Import Extension that allows you to directly query (via SPARQL) or import RDF data. https://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/SemanticWebImport (You can install it directly within the program at Plugins.

[image: Gephi Screenshot]

There's a JavaScript Graph Visualisation Library which worked quiet nice for me: [http://sigmajs.org](http://sigmajs.org/)/ It works well together with Gephi since you can Export your graph from there and import the file into SigmaJS. That way you can export your graph to an interactive web site. Example: http://fannon.de/p/smw/vis/George_Orwell_Platz_30.html

[image]

An important mention would be [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) which has already dozends of force graph examples. But it doesn't support RDF directly, so the data has to be converted first.

A nice one is this: http://nylen.tv/d3-process-map/graph.php?dataset=les-mis

[image]

Answer (score 16):

[RDF Gravity](http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/index.html) is an RDF visualisation tool.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: RDF Gravity Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [salzburgresearch.at](http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/html/owl_ontology_1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Website is currently down. Screenshot https://web.archive.org/web/20161121211502im_/http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/html/owl_ontology_1.jpg and download https://web.archive.org/web/20161208093431/http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at:80/apps/rdf-gravity/download.html

Answer (score 11):

WebVOWL is a great choice for visualizing ontologies. http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl.html

[image]

Comment: This one is open source and great for who want to use such tools in browser without installation onto their desktop operating system.

Comment: Does WebVOWL work well with very large ontologies?

Comment: WebVOWL is very good for visualising ontologies (aka schemas), but not knowledge graphs, since it does not visualise instances.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for one too and i found this : https://gephi.org/
Pretty sure it works with rdf.

Comment: Gephi has a Semantic Web Extension which lets you query or import RDF directly. It also has a lot of graph layouting and analyzing capabilities. This makes Gephi my current favorite.

Comment: It only allows for .rdf and .rdfs files. Not .ttl or .nq. Moreover, https:// endpoint don't seem supported.

Comment: Version 0.10 does not support SemanticWebExtension plugin. Old versions like does.

Answer (score 9):

-Cytoscape http://www.cytoscape.org/ works well with large scale graphs and you can create a static pdf or image.

-I also found this very interesting http://d3js.org/

It's not specific to RDF graphs, but in the examples there seems to be some cool functionality where the users could have a large degree of interaction with the data. It does however require a fair amount of JS programming knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Protégé.
Activate Tools > Tabs > Jambalaya.

[image]
<sub>(source: [utexas.edu](https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~i385t-sw/archive/protege/protege-jambalaya-02.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks gizmo, but I did specifically request screen shots.  You could have gotten some reputation by posting a link to protege and a screenshot.  It's less for me than it is for others that are coming to view this post in the future.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~i385t-sw/archive/protege/protege-jambalaya-02.png

Comment: The [Jambalaya](https://thechiselgroup.org/jambalaya/) project has been retired and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 7):

[RDFShape](http://rdfshape.weso.es) which is also based on Graphviz can be useful to visualize small RDF graphs for presentations. It allows both SVG and PNG output formats. An example visualization can be [this one](http://rdfshape.weso.es/dataInfo?data=%40prefix%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%40prefix%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%40prefix%20xsd%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%20.%0A%40prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%3Aalice%20%20schema%3Agender%20%20schema%3AFemale%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aknows%20%20%20%3Abob%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%20%20%20%22Alice%22%20.%0A%0A%3Abob%20%20%20%20schema%3AbirthDate%20%20%221980-03-10%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Agender%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AMale%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Robert%22%20.%0A%0A%3Acarol%20%20schema%3Agender%20%20schema%3AFemale%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%20%20%20%22Carol%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aage%20%20%20%20%20%20%2023%20.&dataFormat=TURTLE&inference=NONE)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it does not seem very well maintained or explained. For your example visualisation, I'm getting `Error response from https://api.rdfshape.weso.es/api/data/info: Error: Network Error`.

Comment: You may be right that in the past it was not well maintained, however, we have been working in the last months in a new version and now it is more stable. You can try again and we will appreciate any feedback or suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The Perl utility rdfdot, based on Graphviz, and this library, might help:

http://metacpan.org/pod/RDF::Trine::Exporter::GraphViz

https://github.com/nichtich/RDF-Trine-Exporter-GraphViz

Graphviz is able to handle thousands of nodes, and therefore might suit the scale of your problem..

Comment: This can no longer be  installed on Linux/Ubuntu. Pre-installation test fails: `t/serialize.t : Failed test 'edges' ... $got->[0] = 'Z -> node1 [label="skos:narrower",' ...  $expected->[0] = 'Z -> node1 [label="skos:narrower", style=bold];' Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.`

Comment: Indeed this CPAN module has not been updated for many years, but that specific testsuite failure [seems just harmless whitespace changes](https://github.com/nichtich/RDF-Trine-Exporter-GraphViz/issues/3) - try suppress testsuite errors while installing the module, e.g. with `cpanm --force ...`

Answer (score 3):

Commandline with *rapper* and *graphviz*:

`$ rapper --input ntriples $fname.nt --output dot > $fname.dot
$ dot -Tpng $fname.dot > $fname.png`

Comment: rapper documentation: https://librdf.org/raptor/rapper.html

Answer (score 0):

A couple of visually appealing additional alternatives, although IMHO they are not that well suited for visualizing extremely large RDF datasets:

- [RDF Playground](https://rdfplayground.dcc.uchile.cl/) by Bastián Inostroza, Raúl Cid, Pablo Jaramillo, Rodrigo Iturrieta, Giuliano Celedón at the Univ. of Chile.
- [RDF Sketch](https://sketch.zazuko.com/) by Zazuko.